# Can't Update Table Using Prompt

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to select a value in a table based on a User Prompt and then update that value with a user prompt.  If no value in the table is found the no data found exception will be thrown.

I've been able to select the record and output a string based on the Prompt.  The problem comes in when I ask for the new zip code and update.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

ACCEPT p_find_zip PROMPT 'Please enter a 5 digit zip code:'
ACCEPT p_new_zip PROMPT 'Please enter a the new 5 digit zip code:';


DECLARE

 find_zip char(5) :=&p_find_zip;
new_zip char(5) :=&p_new_zip;
v_zip  char(5);



BEGIN


SELECT zip
INTO v_zip
FROM zipcodes
WHERE zip = find_zip;

UPDATE CASCADE zipcodes 
SET zip = new_zip 
WHERE find_zip = v_zip;




EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THAT ZIP IS NOT IN THE DATABASE');


END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `UPDATE` a table named `CASCADE`:

```
UPDATE CASCADE zipcodes
```

Just get rid of the `CASCADE`, and it should work as expected.

**UPDATE**

Oracle doesn't support `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. You should rethink your data model - use a surrogate key instead of a natural one, and then, you should never have to update your primary keys / foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, zip is a foreign key in other table.  I need to be able to cascade the changes.

Comment: Which database is it, @Matt? Does its syntax support `update cascade`? If not, you'll have to *cascade* it yourself, table by table.

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.  I tried using On Update Cascade in the table creation but it doesn't seem to accept it.  I get the red squiggle.

Comment: "Oracle SQL Developer" is not a database. However that does suggest you are using Oracle. Documentation for `update` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5).

Comment: Also the substitution variables `&p_find_zip` etc are missing quotes, and `char` should probably be `varchar2`.